# document.registerElement for modern browsers

Tags: javascript, android, backwards-compatibility

We are using a library in our company, the code is not updated from last few years. The thing is that we are using `document.registerElement`, which is replaced by `window.customElements.define`

We are facing backward compatibility issue with android's latest updates, our code is not working in android app's webview. Though it's working fine on mobile web browser and desktop browser too.

Can you provide me with a function that can define `document.registerElement` for modern browser?

Something like this:

```
<script>
  if (!document.registerElement) {
    class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {}
    document.registerElement = (tagName, options) => {
      customElements.define(tagName, MyCustomElement, options);
      return MyCustomElement;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Use this `  if (document.registerElement) {` instead of `!`

Comment: i tried that too, getting error. `Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this constructor has already been used with this registry`.

btw we need to define `registerElement` if it's not defined already in browser. In older browsers it's already defined.

Comment: somehow resolved duplicate definition, but still the overridden definition not showing results on mobile app.